# How do I copy everything into the next line

Tags: python, concurrency, command-line-interface, chat

I am trying to write a threaded chat app with Python. I want to listen to the received messages and print it. But the problem is when I am writing my message to the prompt and receive a message, it is printing next to what I was writing.

I want to somehow print the received message on the screen and continue writing my message on the next line.

I am trying to do it with `\033]A` things, and avoid using libraries because it will be used by other people and nobody wants to install packages.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
Sent: Hi
Sent: are you there
>>> I am writing | <- This is where my cursor is
```

And a message comes, then the magic happens:

```
Sent: Hi
Sent: are you there
Received: Yes, I am here
>>> I am writing | <- Now, I continue to write from here (next line)
```

I am trying it with `sys.stdout.write("\033[F")` and something like that. But couldn't figure it out.

I hope I explained, Thank you all.

Comment: use the `curses` library for full-screen console applications.

Comment: is it built in? `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'`, i mean do users has to pip install it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html